# Pusher expired timestamp

Tags: laravel, pusher

i have an issue with pusher in laravel production, it fine in localhost. How i solve this without change timezone in server. I use cluster ap1.

> Message: Pusher error: Timestamp expired: Given timestamp (2021-12-27-T01:25:34Z) not wihtin 600s of server time  (2021-12-17T02:16:07Z)

sorry for my english, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the *Datetime* of your production server is outdated.

Updating your NTP server config will fix the issue.